# Can I get TeamCity to DISABLE a build if a different build has failing tests?

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I have a TeamCity job that builds my project and runs all the unit tests, and another one that deploys the build to the production server.

Can I disable the "deploy" job so that it's impossible to deploy code if there's currently a failing test in the build project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't the deploy job already be dependent on the build one? Through Artifacts Dependency? You can set up the build trigger for the deploy job to be a successful build trigger on the build job so that the deploy happens when there is a successful build. Also, if a deploy job is triggered, it will take the last successful build. So if unit tests in the build job are failing, that build is not considered.

I wouldn't recommend snapshot dependency though, because it means when you deploy you try to trigger a new build, that is not the logical flow. Of course in the snapshot dependency you can say trigger only if a suitable build is not available ( or something like that ) but still snapshot dependency is not the way to go for this case.

Answer (score 2):

Set up a Snapshot Dependency for Deploy on the most recetly finished Build and make sure the properties to say reject if failed [and make sure Build fails if tests fail in the General settings]